# Checking if page has updated on the server with JS

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am wondering if there is a simple (?) way to use JS to check if there is an update to the current page? Use AJAX to load the page and check against the current DOM? Is this possible?

Thanks,
Isaac

Comment: Check whether the page modification date > load date by checking the headers (no idea how to do that, though).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use XHR to load the page and then compare the page to the current, but it would be overkill. Serialising the DOM to do a string comparison would be a lot of unnecessary work for the JavaScript interpreter.

Instead, why not create a service, e.g. JSON, that lets you tell your page when something has updated instead of scraping the entire output?

Comment: Ahh... now that might work. Some sort of versioning system? Good idea!

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is a polling solution. The easiest way to do this is to separate out your page into pieces so that you can poll only for the content that is going to be updated, and then be able to pass in a time string to check for updates since the last time you polled, so you can filter your results. Doing a full page comparison would be slow at best.

If you're just looking to do a refresh of the whole page every few minutes, you can always use (the somewhat out of date) [meta refresh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh) tag.

Comment: Yeah, that's not going to work... the page is large, and the reason that I am thinking of polling is to not refresh unless necessary.

Comment: Yeah, breaking it up into pieces and doing JSON is your best bet then.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of comparing entire DOM,You can maintain a hidden variable in your page to have the version number.Use Ajax to load the page, and get the version number from the loaded data and compare against the version number in DOM.
You can also use service to get the version number only from the server instead of loading entire page every time.